# Perform string replace using column name as string value to replace with

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform a string replace on my dataframe where I find all instances of "X" in a column and replace it with the column name.

ex

```
Name  FFF1  H0L1
  -    L     -
  -    X     L
  X    -     -
  -    -     X
```

result df after replace

```
Name     FFF1      H0L1
  -      FFF1        -
  -      FFF1      H0L1
Name      -          -
  -       -        H0L1
```

It seems pretty straightforward, I am just confused on how to "reference" the column name. Thoughts?

Comment: is it for all columns? or a particular series? try : `df['Name']=np.where(df['Name'].eq('X'),df['Name'].name,df['Name'])` ?

Comment: @anky_91 I would like to do it for every column in the dataframe

Comment: Please, give some data to get ahead.

Comment: @kantal updated, the assumption is that there can be any number of columns that can be named anything. There will only ever be `L` and `X` in the columns and they are to be replaced with whatever the column name is.

Comment: @MaxB Is there always one chacter in the cell that needs to be replaced? See the edited code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'apply' method iterates over the columns as series which 'name' attribute corresponds to the column name:

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.where(~col.str.contains("X"), \
                        col.str.replace("X",col.name)) )
```

Even better:

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace("X",col.name))
```

**Edit:**
Answering the additional question:
Use regular expression:

```
#df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(r"([^X]|^)(X)([^X]|$)",r"\1"+col.name+r"\3")) # didn't work correctly in all situation, e.g.: "aXbXcXd"
df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(r"([^X]|^)(X)(?=[^X]|$)",r"\1"+col.name))


"""  The details:
     We create three pattern groups: (...) 
     [^X] can be any char but X (^ in square br. negates the chars)  
     ^ as a separate char means start of string; 
     $ means end of string; 
     | means 'or'. 
     \1 and \2 mean the corresponding groups;
     (?=...) lookahead check
"""
```

**Edit 2:**
If there is always one char in the cell to be replaced:

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.replace(["X","L"],col.name))
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this solution more explicit so that it doesn't work when it finds partial matches? Example: `XX` would not yield a match, but `X` would

Comment: The updated solution still seems to behave the same way as the initial solution. In reality I have 300 columns of varying 4 letter strings (letters and numbers), so maybe it is an error on my end.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `df.where`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['-', 'X'],
                   'B': ['X', '-']})
df.where(df.eq('X'), df.columns)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  A  X
1  X  B
```